# remove weight decimals in frontend

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, javascript, css, html

I'm using `Magento 1.8.1 CE` and I want change weight attribute.
How can I remove `weight decimals` from frontend?
My products weight is showing this way: `12.0000` and I want it to be like this: `12` without any decimal.
i followed removing price decimals but it doesn't work on weight!
I am using a custom template.

Comment: "I followed removing price decimals but it doesn't work on weight" maybe you could add the steps that you have tried here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer depends on how you are outputting the weight attribute, so it depends on your specific template.

If your template is following best practices, or you are - for example - displaying the weight in the additional information area of the product detail page, you can assign a custom frontend model to the weight attribute to format it in any way you want.

You should first create a setup script:

```
<?php
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'weight', 'frontend_model', 'your_module/entity_attribute_frontend_weight');
```

Then, create the frontend model:

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Weight
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Abstract
{
    public function getValue(Varien_Object $object)
    {
        return (string) intval(parent::getValue($object));
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you are simply calling

```
<?php echo $_product->getWeight() ?>
```

somewhere in your template, then you would have to do the formatting in your template directly.

Comment: I'm new to magento I will tbe hankful if you explain it by details.

Comment: Learning how to create a module and with a setup resource is out of scope of this answer I'm afraid. There are many online tutorials on how to create an extension. Then look for resources on what you need to add so the extension can have setup scripts. Both things (creating a module and adding a setup resource) are actually pretty small things, but if you want to know how they work, they need a lot of explanation. Finally, the purpose of EAV attribtue frontend models is to prepare values for displaying. So thats is why it is a pretty good match for what you want.